# Error while connecting to remote postgressql database using jsch in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jsch

I have the following code snippet:

```
jsch.addIdentity(configuration.getSSHPrivateKeyPath(), "...");
jsch.setKnownHosts("...");
session = jsch.getSession("...", configuration.getIp(), 22);
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
config.put("Compression", "yes");
config.put("ConnectionAttempts","2");
session.setConfig(config);
Proxy proxy = new ProxyHTTP("...", ...);
session.setProxy(proxy);
session.connect();
session.setPortForwardingL(configuration.getLocalPort(), configuration.getIp(), 5432);
```

I'm able to connect and establish the port forwarding. However, when I issue the following code:

```
nucConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://" + "localhost:" + configuration.getLocalPort() + "/" + configuration.getDbname(), configuration.getDbuser(), configuration.getDbpass());
```

I get the following exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:156)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:35)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:47)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:414)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:282)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at se.foi.oculusdb.rest.server.datapipe.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:185)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:112)
    at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:71)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.ReceiveChar(PGStream.java:282)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:405)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:203)
    ... 12 more
```

I have no problem whatsoever when using psql on the remote machine with the credentials and database. Is there a PostgreSQL configuration I have to make?

PS
Before going the Jsch route I used the following code:

```
key = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh-add " + configuration.getSSHPrivateKeyPath());
Thread.sleep(1000);
ssh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ssh -i " + configuration.getSSHPrivateKeyPath() +  " -L " + configuration.getLocalPort() + ":localhost:5432 gnu-radio-usr@" + configuration.getIp());
```

which would run for an arbitrary number of hours before getting the exception above. That was the reason I switched to Jsch.
Ds

Comment: Does the full stack trace have any network or io exceptions?

Comment: This looks more like a networking firewall issue rather than postgresql configuration. Did you try setting up the tunnel using the ssh client and using psql to connect through that?

Comment: Hmmm interesting... FYI I included a code snippet I used based on Runtime.getRuntime().exec() which actually worked for an arbitrary number of hours. Could this bring some light?

Comment: I used to work with Jsch many many years ago, I've forgotten most of it's intracacies but one thing I remembered was that sometimes errors are not what it appears to be. The SocketException does indicate that problem is with the connectivity rather than postgresql settings. One thing I noticed is that you are setting a proxy. That's not needed no harm removing it and then trying.

Comment: I really appreciate your input here but I've tried both with and without with no avail...:( Thanks anyway...